# Is there a way to extract certain info from a string? c++

Tags: c++

I need to read in some lines from a text file (amount of lines will be known during run time) but an example could be something like this:

Forecast.txt:

```
Day 0:S
Day 3:W
Day 17:N
```

My idea was to create a class which I did:

```
class weather
{
  int day;
  char letter;
};
```

Then create a vector of class as so:

```
vector<wather>forecast;
```

and now here is where I'm stuck. So I think I'd use a while loop?

id use my ifstream to read the info in and use a string to hold the information im reading in.

What I want to do is read in each line and extract the day number so in this example the 0, 3 and 15 and get the letter so S, W, N and store it in the vector of the class.

I was wondering if there's any way to do that? I could be coming at this wrong so forgive me im new to c++ and trying to figure this out.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: *I was wondering if there's any way to do that?* -- A language that has the power of C++, and you're asking if there is a way to read simple data from a file.  LOL.  Of course there is.

Comment: There are many ways how to do this with a `std::string`. You should at least show what you've tried yourself, and where you stuck with it. I've been voting to close that question as _too broad_.

Comment: Are you crazy to remove the whole contents of your question with something meaningless?? You seem to have seriously missed the purpose of this site, It's not meant as a personal helpdesk to solve your problems, but to build a FAQ like repository that helps for any future research about programming problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your can use `std::istringstream` to parse each line, eg:

```
#include <sstream>

while (getline(in_s1, lines2))
{
    istringstream iss(lines2);
    string ignore1; // "Day" 
    char ignore2; // ":" 
    forecast f;
    if (iss >> ignore1 >> f.day >> ignore2 >> f.letter)
        weather.push_back(f);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/nvWWj1)

Alternatively, you can parse each line using [`std::regex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) and [related classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Comment: drop the `using namespace std`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that is irrelevant to the topic at hand

Comment: @Remy And [that's](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56606999/2) what we get, when answering such questions. Don't encourage those askers by giving answers at all please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've often found elaborate answers to _bad_ questions very helpful. It takes some skill to ask a good question or knowing what to search for. Remy's answers to my questions have helped me tremendously because they've been very specific, very rarely generic, even though the questions have probably been asked many times in some form or another. Getting the question/reply you linked to is of course a risk one takes when taking on such questions but it's atypical.

Answer (score 1):

`istringstream` and the `>>` operator is probably the neatest C++ way to do it, as described in [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56607027/3697870). In case you prefer to be a little less reliant on the stream magic and a bit more explicit, you can `find` the tokens you need and then extract them directly from the string.

Something like this:

```
while (getline(in_s1, lines2))
{
    size_t startPos = lines2.find(' '); //get position of the space before the day
    size_t endPos = lines2.find(':', startPos); //get position of the colon after the day
    string day = lines2.substr (startPos+1, endPos-startPos-1); //extract the day

    forecast f;
    f.day = stoi(day); //stoi only supported since C++11, otherwise use atoi
    f.letter = lines2[endPos+1];

    weather.push_back(f);
}
```

Comment: [Same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606999/is-there-a-way-to-extract-certain-info-from-a-string-c#comment99790121_56607027) for you.